# How to run a loop over certain numbers only

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I wanted to run a for loop for 1,7,14,19.I know this is a basic question but I could not get the idea.I tried with

```
 for(int i=1;;i++){
     if(i==1||i==7||i==14||i==19){
         System.out.println(i);
     } else if(i==20){
         break;
     } else{

     }          
 }
```

But this keeps on printing.Also same with below code

```
for(int i=1;(i==1||i==7||i==14||i==19);i++){
    System.out.println(i);      
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if 1,7,14,19 were in an array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use an array

```
for (int i : new int[] { 1, 7, 14, 19 }) {
    // something with i
```

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8+, you could use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). Like,

```
IntStream.of(1, 7, 14, 19).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array and for each

```
int ary[]= { 1, 7, 14, 19} ;
for(int i : ary){
System.out.println(i);
}
```